# How to prevent buttons from submitting form

Tags: jquery, json

I want to get some data from a `JSON` page using JSP. The `JSON` receives an argument userId, based on userId user details is populated in the JSON page. I am using `getJSON()` method to get the data form the page. But, my problem is when a button is clicked, the form is submitted. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjDTq/1/) is the one without `getJSON()` method doesn't submit the form after pressing submit but, [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/u9LVL/) the form is submitted after I click a button. I am returning `false` still of no use.

Please tell me how can I get the data form the JSON without submitting the form. If there are any alternative or better approach please suggest one.

Here is my code:

```
$("input[name=submit]").click(function(){
    var dataToBeSent = $("form").serialize();
    alert (dataToBeSent);
    $.getJSON(url,dataToBeSent, function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
        });
        $('div').html($('<ul/>', {
            'class' : 'my-new-list',
            html : items.join(' ')
        }));
    });
    return false;
```

Regards

Dibya

Comment: are you looking for [preventDetault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) ?

Comment: I didnt know use of preventDefault..

Comment: I like this [reference](http://dev-tricks.com/event-preventdefault-and-event-stoppropagation-and-event-stopimmediatepropagation/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to do event.preventDefault()

```
$("input[name=submit]").click(function(e){
    ................
    ................
    ................
    ................
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

return false doesn't stop event as it not similar to object.onclick. to stop default behavior you must use preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning it into a function return instead of an event listener like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function serializeForm(){
        var dataToBeSent = $("form").serialize();
        alert(dataToBeSent);
        // $.getJSON(); function here
        return false;
    }
</script>
<form action="#submit" method="post" onsubmit="return serializeForm();">
    <input type="text" name="data1" id="data1" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="data2" id="data2" value="2" />
    <input type="text" name="data3" id="data3" value="3" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What is the difference between this code and my demo fiddle? I couldn't find any hence I think this won't work.

Comment: The difference is the onsubmit="" on the form will wait to process the form until the serializeForm() function has run its course. If you return false instead of the default true, it essentially does the same thing as event.preventDefault(); The main thing I'm getting at is the misuse of jQuery. Pointing to a function is more efficient that assigning an event handler.